# Node.js Express POST call not working although GET does

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

I am trying to write a REST backend using Node.js, express and MongoDB but am having some issues creating PUT calls for some reason. The issue is with  app.post('/contacts/add', contacts.addContacts) as it works fine if I change it to GET but when I change it to either PUT or POST I get the error Cannot GET /contacts/add Any ideas?

I am using  express 4.15.3, mongodb 3.4.5 and npm 4.2.0

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    contacts = require('./routes/contacts');
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/contacts/chalkboard/:id', contacts.getChalkboardContacts);
app.get('/contacts/get/:uid', contacts.getContacts);
app.post('/contacts/add', contacts.addContacts);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

contacts.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
mongo.BSONPure = require('bson').BSONPure;

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('db', server);


db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to database");
        db.collection('contacts', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("The 'contacts' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
                populateDB();
            }
        });
    }
});

exports.getChalkboardContacts = function(req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid.toString();
    var date = new Date();
    var timeInMs = date.getMilliseconds();
    console.log(uid);
    db.collection('contacts', function(err, collection) {
        console.log('collection: ' + collection);
        collection.find({uid: uid, lastMessage: {$gte: timeInMs}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};

exports.getContacts = function(req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid.toString();
    console.log(uid);
    db.collection('contacts', function(err, collection) {
        console.log('collection: ' + collection);
        collection.find({uid: uid}).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};

exports.addContacts = function(req, res) {
    console.log('working');
    db.collection('contacts', function(err, collection) {
        var id = "592159bc3e48764418170399";
        var contact = {uid: "592159bc3e48764418173333", 
               keyUid: "592159bc3e48764418171444", 
               name: "Billy Jean", 
               phoneNumber: "+491721894733", 
               battery: "47%", longitude: "0", 
               latitude: "0", 
               city: "city", 
               country: "country", 
               place: "place", 
               address: "address", 
               lastMessage: "lastMessage", 
               lastUpdated: "lastUpdated"};
        collection.update({'uid':id}, {$push:{'contacts':contact}}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error updating contact: ' + err);
                res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
                res.send(result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Your client is making a `GET` request. Your client code needs to be updated to make a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't spot anything immediately wrong with the code.

You might be falling into a very common pitfall when using `body-parser` for JSON. Your request **must** specify `Content-Type: application/json` in the request for the parser to parse it. Otherwise, it won't work.

If that doesn't do the trick, if you can share any error messages or response codes you get, it may illuminate another issue.

Comment: Thank you it was indeed a problem with the request from the client side (I was testing using a browser). Once I made an API call within my Android app it worked fine.

Comment: @RileyMacDonald It may have know to use application/json. A lot of applications will in certain scenarios.